# Как достать название папки, в которой лежит файл?

Tags: php

Есть две папки:

`/var/www/developer/main/about/index.php`

`/var/www/production/main/about/index.php`

Оба файла идентичны и дублируют друг-друга. Мне нужно, чтобы `index.php` в папке /about/ распознавал, лежит ли он в папке /developer/, или же в папке /production/. Также, работоспособность скрипта должна сохраняться на любом уровне вложенности. Если я, например, захочу переместить скрипт в папку `/var/www/developer/main/about/more/index.php`. Итогом работы скрипта должна быть строка `'developer'` или `'production'`. Как это можно сделать и при помощи каких функций?

Answer (score 2):

Можно создать простую функцию которая будет смотреть текущую директорию файла и через регулярку забрать нужное вам значение:

```
function environment()
{
    preg_match('/www\/(\w+)/', __DIR__, $matches);

    if (empty($matches[1])) {
        throw new \Exception('Что-то пошло не так');
    }

    return $matches[1];
}

var_dump(environment());
```

На выходе будет то что вы и просили.

Answer (score 2):

С помощью **[__DIR__](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.constants.predefined.php)** узнаем путь файла, а с помощью **[strpos](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php)**
 определяем есть ли в пути например `developer` и делаем в зависимости от этого то, что задумали.

Comment: `echo strpos(__DIR__, 'developer');` вернёт мне просто `9`. Как мне исходя из позиции определить `'developer'` или `'production'`?

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin ну проверь на `/var/www/developer`. Начальный путь все равно же известен..... к тому же, раз вернулось положительное число- значит developer. Разве не очевидно?

Comment: А, всё, понял. Могу же просто условие добавить, что если `strpos(__DIR__, 'developer') !== false` то `return 'developer'`. Спасибо!

Comment: да именно так... если конечно не может встречаться внезапно в пути что-то типа `/var/www/production/main/about/who/are/you/my/developer/index.php` %))  Но опять же. на такой случай можно проверять на вхождение не просто `developer/production` а к примеру `/var/www/developer`